# Python: Sorting a list in ascending order and splitting it

Tags: python

For example: I have a list whichis:

`[0,15,1,7,2,16]`

And i would need to output that list into

`[(1,7),(0,15),(2,16)]`.

Whereby, every two terms from the start is split and also the second term of the sublist is arranged in ascending order.

Is there a way to perform this without the use of any python library functions except import math?

Comment: Ah so this is a homework assignment...?? And have you tried solving it yourself?

Comment: it was an extra challenge that isn't assessed. I got this list from other series of calculations. I was thinking if i use a for loop to find the min value of the 2nd element then sort through there.

Comment: Well in any case it is nice to show some effort in solving the problem when you ask for help in SO, otherwise it gives the feeling that you simply want others to do some task for you

Comment: i see. I will give it a go myself and post it up in a bit

Answer (score 1):

With list comprehension and sorted method

```
l1 = [0,15,1,7,2,16]
def on_sec(v):
    return v[1]
print(sorted ([(l1[e], l1[e+1]) for e in range(0, len(l1), 2)], key=on_sec))

# OUTPUT: [(1, 7), (0, 15), (2, 16)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = [0,15,1,7,2,16]
b = sorted([a[n:n+2] for n in range(0, len(a), 2)], key = lambda x: x[1])
print(b)    # OUTPUT : [[1, 7], [0, 15], [2, 16]]
```

Comment: i have tried your code but it doesn't output anything to the command window

Comment: @Tony Try with assigning a variable like `b  = sorted(..)` and then `print(b)`. Should work

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is very useful for these kind of splitting operations. We can use `reshape` to split it into pairs, and then sort based on the second element.

```
import numpy as np

l = [0,15,1,7,2,16]
split = np.reshape(l, (-1,2))
sorted(split, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Alternatively we can also do the sorting using numpy:

```
split[split[:,1].argsort()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0,15,1,7,2,16] 
l = [] 
for i in range(0,len(a),2): 
    c = (a[i],a[i+1]) 
    l.append(c) 

l.sort() 
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `sorted()` with a key:

```
l = [0, 15, 1, 7, 2, 16]

sorted(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]), key=lambda x: x[1])
# [(1, 7), (0, 15), (2, 16)]
```